# Elements greater than certain number

Tags: c

I would like to find the number of elements greater than a given number in an array.
Like if I have the following array: { 10, 113, 34, 2, 19, 57}
And want to look for numbers greater than 30 then I would get 3.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 10, 113, 34, 2, 19, 57}; 
    int n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); 
    int A = 30;
    
    int l = 0; 
    int r = n - 1; 
    
    int leftGreater = n;
  
    while (l <= r) { 
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2; 
  
        if (array[m] > A) { 
            leftGreater = m; 
            r = m - 1; 
        } 
  
        else
            l = m + 1; 
        
    } 
    printf("%d",n - leftGreater);
}
```

But instead of 3, I'm getting 5.
Can anyone please help me solve this?

Comment: What are all those variables `l`, `r`, `leftGreater` mean? Are you doing some binary search in an unsorted array?

Comment: I don't understand what `l`, `r`, `m` or `leftGreater` are for, either. It looks like a binary search. Binary search only works if the array is sorted, which yours is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `for` loop is enough:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = { 10, 113, 34, 2, 19, 57 }; 
    int n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); 
    int x = 30, res = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > x)
        {
            res++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```